# Strange behavior creating a new Database with Npgsql and Entity Framework

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, postgresql, npgsql

I'm trying to create a new database with npgsql and EF 6. This is my code:

```
using System.Data.Common;
using System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure;
using System.Data.Entity.Migrations;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Sql;
using Npgsql;
using NUnit.Framework;

namespace EntityFramework.PostgreSql.Test.IntegrationTests
{

    [TestFixture]
    public class PostgreSqlMigrationSqlGeneretorHistoryTest
    {

        private const string ConnectionString = "Server=127.0.0.1;Port=5432;Database=testEF6;User Id=postgres;Password=p0o9i8u7y6;CommandTimeout=20;Preload Reader = true;";
        private const string ProviderName = "Npgsql";


        [Test]
        public void CreateNewDatabase()
        {


            const string cs = "Server=127.0.0.1;Port=5432;Database=testEFxx;User Id=postgres;Password=p0o9i8u7y6;CommandTimeout=20;Preload Reader = true;";

            var db = new LocalPgContext(cs);


            if (!db.Database.Exists())
                db.Database.Create();

            var exists = db.Database.Exists();


            db.Database.Delete();

            Assert.IsTrue(exists);

        }

        public class LocalPgContext : DbContext, IDbProviderFactoryResolver, IDbConnectionFactory
        {

            public LocalPgContext(string nameOrConnectionString) : base(nameOrConnectionString)
            {
                Database.SetInitializer(new CreateDatabaseIfNotExists<LocalPgContext>());
            }


            public DbProviderFactory ResolveProviderFactory(DbConnection connection)
            {
                return DbProviderFactories.GetFactory("Npgsql");
            }

            public DbConnection CreateConnection(string nameOrConnectionString)
            {
                return new NpgsqlConnection(nameOrConnectionString);
            }

            DbConnection IDbConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(string nameOrConnectionString)
            {
                return CreateConnection(nameOrConnectionString);
            }

            DbProviderFactory IDbProviderFactoryResolver.ResolveProviderFactory(DbConnection connection)
            {
                return new LocalPgProviderFactory();
            }

        }

        public class LocalPgProviderFactory : DbProviderFactory
        {

            public override DbConnectionStringBuilder CreateConnectionStringBuilder()
            {
                return new NpgsqlConnectionStringBuilder(ConnectionString);
            }

            public override DbConnection CreateConnection()
            {
                return new NpgsqlConnection(ConnectionString);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The strange thing is that I create a new connection using Npgsql but when I'm executing `if (!db.Database.Exists())` it try to create a connection using SqlServer provider. It tell me that it doesn't know the "port" attribute of the connection string because sql server haven't this attribute.

I'm thinking that it is looking for the default provider factory into the web.config file but not finding it, it set sql server as default provider.
I would like to set Npgsql as default provider without using a config file at all.

Answer (score 0):

Npgsql add the support to delete or create the database from the 2.2.0 version (now is in beta 1)